# Enable Mod_Security for only one website

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

Is there a way to dis-able mod-security for all websites? except one?
i have more than 500 websites hosted, only want to turn it on for one website, which is having attacks on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I suppose it is possible if you enable the configuration for mod security <strike>either in .htaccess or</strike> in the virtual host apache configuration for that particular domain using something like this :

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine On
    ...... (any other directives you might want to override from the defaul conf)
</IfModule>
```

Also in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf`, or wherever the defaul config is stored, set `SecRuleEngine Off` but leave the other directives in place.

Comment: care to point out where I was wrong and why the answer was not useful?
Just so that I know where I got it wrong. I usually do the exact opposite because I might need to temporarily disable mod_security on a particular website while I figure the problem while having it enabled on all other websites

Comment: I also don't see where this answer is wrong, and would be very interested to know.

Comment: Giving error: "/httpdocs/.htaccess: SecRuleEngine not allowed here"
Also, for latest mod-security, it is mod_security2.c and its not SecFilterEngine but SecRuleEngine.

Comment: You are actually quite correct on both points. Kick me on the head for checking an old test server for the actual configuration and doing a copy paste without thinking much. Sorry about that and leason learned.
Now going back to the original question: if .htaccess is not allowed for whatever reason can you move the mod_security configuration the the virtual host apache configuration ?
I mean completely remove modsec config from httpd.conf and move anything you might need to the virtual host.

Comment: yes, moved the this configuraton portion to vhost configuration file, and its working now. Thanks

Comment: no problems and sorry for messing up the original answer. answering too quickly and thinking too little really.